# Do the pendants wirelessly supply power to nearby devices?

Tags: revolution

The first time we see a pendant being used, it powers up a computer and a lightbulb. The power company has long since ceased operating, and there isn't evidence of a generator.

Supposedly the field that was created suppressed electricity (and disrupted the laws of physics), but does the inverse field created by the pendants produce spontaneous electricity wirelessly to all nearby devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pendants don't supply power themselves. The power is already present, but the nanobots are holding it in. The pendants basically reprogram the nanobots to behave differently,

The show has been very bad at explaining some of the phenomenon we see, so there is no explanation that anyone can give you that won't have holes in it. What has happened so far just doesn't appear to match the known laws of physics. But, the basic idea is that the nanobots are *storing* electric power. Their original goal was to provide universal free electricity to the world; their ability to absorb it from the environment was an unintended side-effect. The pendants contain remit programming command that override the nanobots default behavior and tell them to temporarily stop absorbing power. The assumption I have been making its that they refer to their other behavior of supplying* power to nearby devices instead of stealing it.

Answer (score 2):

This phenomena doesn't make any sense.  Prior to the reveal of the nanobots, you could maybe argue that battery-powered devices would resume working near the pendants because the cessation of electricity somehow also prevented the batteries from losing their charge (or from leaking battery acid all over the inside of the device  **cough**).  Then once the pendant was turned on, the charge was then able to flow again.  However, the pendants and nanobots were explained thusly:

1. Nanobots are in the air everywhere.
2. When electricity would flow, the nanobots take in the energy and use it to self-replicate.
3. The pendants suppress the nanobots nearby.

Number 2 means the explanations in the other answers don't work.  The nanobots aren't storing anything, they're powering their self-replication with the electricity, so there's no stored electricity that the pendants/nanobots could provide.  Once the pendant is turned on, I would expect you'd need to then turn on a generator to make use of any electronic devices.  Or, you'd have to build new batteries if you're powering mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that we don't really know how the nanobots on the atmosphere affect electricity exactly, and I don't think we'll ever will.

The way I understand it, is that the nanobots store electricity, removing it from the devices that use it, effectively removing power from all electric dependent machines. And what the pendants do, is make the nanobots spit out that store electricity, making nearby electric devices / machines start working.

I get that my explanation is probably not very scientific and I'm sure there are at least 100 physic laws that I'm violating, but I don't think those really apply when you have the atmosphere of the entire planet filled with nanobots that prevent electric devices from working :S

Answer (score 1):

Rachel explained this on Episode 9 of Season 1 (Kashmir)

She said that a pendant can power up anything in its range, like a wireless **battery**.

But the pendant itself has its own flaws; it can only power up to 9-10 feet. And can only power a CD player or a computer and a bunch of small electronics without an amplifier - a device that can extend the pendant's range to a half-mile radius.